# GPS icon not disappearing when google maps api is being used in the app. iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps, cllocationmanager

I am using google maps in my application and the problem is that even if i use **stopUpdatingLocation** and **stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**, the GPS icon will not go away. I think it is because of google maps in the application. My Question is that how to remove GPS icon when using google maps?

Comment: Did you mean the default blue icon? How did you add the icon? You might paste some code about how you add the icon.

Comment: @ztan I mean the default icon at the top of screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning **myLocationEnabled** property to NO should do the job. Here is the code:

```
 self.googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;
```